# WinRt WebView control handling navigation within the control

Tags: windows-8, webview, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a Metro app using a WebView control.  I'm using `NavigateToString` to load a html file which may contain hyperlinks.  What I then want to do is detect when one of these hyperlinks is selected and, instead of allowing navigation within the WebView control, to launch IE and view the page there instead.

Is this possible within the WinRT constraints, and if so, how?

So far, I've tried capturing the `WebView_LoadCompleted()` event, but although it does fire at the right time, I can't see any details about the URI from the `NavigationEventArgs`.

Comment: Perhaps you could hook up the javascript events in the html DOM and relay them outside of the control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible directly because WebView does not include events like Navigating (which were present in Windows Phone).

Luckily Nick Randolph (brilliant Windows Phone and Windows 8 developer) has created a workaround using script events. He's got a great write up on his blog:

http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2012/04/21/Limitations-of-the-WebView-in-Windows-8-Metro-Apps.aspx

Comment: Can you explain how this worked, because the blog post says "unfortunately there doesn’t seem to be a way to extract the target url..." and this means there is no way to use that code to navigate using IE instead of the WebView control. If you did manage to detect the navigation event and open the destination URI in IE, can you post some code?