# How to load anchor tag link in webview in Store app

Tags: c#, webview, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am loading my XHTML page from my local folder in webview using C#.
I have many files which I want to **redirect from my first page using Anchor Tag to another pages**.(like Content page to sub links) It's not working for me. 
I thought it is issue of Webview or another thing; I am interested know.

Comment: With in page I have another link(anchor tag). I want to open that   page in same page.

Comment: are you opening another XHTML page (`<a href="my.xhtml>My</a>"`) or within same XHTML page (`<a href="#above>Go Above</a>"`) ?

Comment: In this, http://pastebin.com/heN80wyS, you have `<a href="#switch">above</a>`, is it not working ?

Comment: @Xyroid; That is sample code only; I updated the changes for anchor tag.
[http://pastebin.com/bM3dJJLX ]
Can you verify this.

Comment: Please give me XML validated XHTML sample of all the XHTML files, so I can give proper solution.

Comment: @Xyroid Sure, It's not an issue; But how can I share with You;
I want to know one more thing about **"How to load html file in webview metro apps using file protocol"** 
Can any one post me any link for this.
Thanks

Comment: Please don't ask another question within same question, can you please upload project (with XHTML docs) on Skydrive/box/dropbox, so I can solve the issue.

Comment: [http://sdrv.ms/ZJoECN ] 
The storage folder path will be Change for you.
The Blankpage1.xaml.cs is the page right now I am working.

Comment: I think you are getting this kind of error right ? http://blogs.msdn.com/resized-image.ashx/__size/450x0/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-55-85/8688.DebuggerDialog.PNG

Comment: @Xyroid No, 
I added screenshots please verify in Skydrive.
I think the problem is the link in the webview not recognising corresponding link in the folder.
** Have you pasted the XHTML files to storage folder.**

Comment: ok, the screenshot which I gave is while debugging & the screenshot which you gave me is of release mode & I can also regenerate it. I don't know the reason of it. It might be bug.

Comment: Check this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726754/winrt-webview-control-handling-navigation-within-the-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MSDN, it seems bug. [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/279f2f7a-cc9c-427b-b006-6bbeed1d0e23)'s the links that I asked the same question to MSDN forum.

Comment: Thank you. But the "InstalledLocation" is also not working.  
`var XHTML1 = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Assets\nav.xhtml");`  It is loading first page. But it is not navigating to next page. giving same error. Please check this...
[ http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/45e8d626-4c92-43ed-96ad-8c88aaaf0416/#45e8d626-4c92-43ed-96ad-8c88aaaf0416 ]