# WebView and external browser

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Is there any way to prevent (or stop) WebView from opening link (external website) in external browser (without leaving the App)?

I've tried with [WebView.NavigationStarting event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigationstarting) but when I click on a link opening external browser, the event isn't fired.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WinRt WebView control handling navigation within the control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726754/winrt-webview-control-handling-navigation-within-the-control)

Comment: There are few changes in WebView policy since the time the answer was published. So it won't work under WP8.1 - still looking for the solution or workaround.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible out of the box.

However, it's seemingly possible to write a workaround, as demonstrated here: http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2012/04/21/Limitations-of-the-WebView-in-Windows-8-Metro-Apps.aspx

Comment: Looks very promising, thank you for the link. I'll give it a try later.

Comment: Unfortunately with Win 8.1 there are some changes that make this method hard to use - according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview) you cannot add `AlowedUris` on the fly, you have to dectale them in `ApplicationContentUriRules` in manifest file - but I cannot predict which site user will visit. It also  doesn't provide a mothod to cancel the Navigation. With Webview I can follow inside Navigation with NavigationStarting, but not when external browser is fired. I start to miss old WebBrowser ;)